# AES encryption using CryptoJS

Tags: encryption, sha256, cryptojs, pbkdf2, aes-gcm

I have the following requirements regarding encryption of url parameters. As I am newly to CryptoJS I can not figure out how to perform all steps using CryptoJS. Can anybody help me with example code to perform this steps?

**Encrypt Requirements**

1. Generate a secret key from the given password.

   - Receive the password which is coupled with the system name. (This is already available)
   - Generate a random nonce in byte-array as the password’s salt which has a length 16-bytes.
   - Set the number of iterations for secret key as 65536.
   - Set the length of secret key as 256-bit (not bytes).
   - Set the algorithm name for key derivation using PBKDF2 with HMAC and SHA-2.
   - Set the algorithm name of key generation as “AES”.
   - Create a secret key with the function of library or tool with all sets above.
2. Encrypt the JSON-string with the above generated secret key.

   - Generate a random nonce in byte-array as the IV (initial vector) which has a length 12-bytes for encryption.
   - Select encrypt mode for the crypto in your function or tool for encryption.
   - Set the name of crypto algorithm which is for AES in GCM mode and without any padding.
   - Set the length of authentication tag for GCM as 128-bits (not bytes).
   - Convert your JSON-string which contains customer information to a byte-array(plainText) with character set UFT-8.
   - Encrypt the plainText with all sets and the secret key in last step to a new byte-array(cipherText)
3. Prefix the generated IV and password’s salt to the cipherText .

   - Create a new byte-array (cipherTextWithIvSalt).
   - Add the 12-bytes IV in cipherTextWithIvSalt at first.
   - Add the 16-bytes password’s salt in cipherTextWithIvSalt after that.
   - Add the cipherText in cipherTextWithIvSalt at last.
   - cipherTextWithIvSalt is now in form “IV + salt + cipherText”
4. Encode the cipherTextWithIvSalt.

   - Encode the cipherTextWithIvSalt to a new byte-array (encodedCipherTextWithIvSalt) by using Base64
5. Build a displayable encrypted string.

   - Build a new string from byte-array encodedCipherTextWithIvSalt with character set UTF-8.

I have tried to do it myself but it does not work here is the example of my js code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
let secretKey = generateKey(salt);
let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(96 / 8);
let JSON_String = "{"Name":"Max", "Firstname":"Mustermann"}";
let plainText = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON_String);
          
let cipherText = encryptJSONString(plainText, secretKey, iv);
let cipherTextWithIvSalt = prefixCipherTextWithSaltAndIV(iv, secretKey, cipherText);
let encodedCipherTextWithIvSalt = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherTextWithIvSalt);

let displayableText = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(encodedCipherTextWithIvSalt);
function generateKey(password) {
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
    return CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, { keySize: 256 / 32, iterations: 65536, hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256 });
 }
function encryptJSONString(plainText, secretKey, iv) {
            //mode: CryptoJS.mode.GCM
            return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, secretKey, { iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });
        }
function prefixCipherTextWithSaltAndIV(iv, secretKey, cipherText) {
            let byteArray = [];
            byteArray.push(iv.words);
            byteArray.push(secretKey.words);
            byteArray.push(cipherText);
            return byteArray;
        }
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [CryptoJS does not support GCM](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding), you need another library.

Comment: It does support CCM (also authenticated encryption) if memory serves me right, but if GCM  your requirement you indeed need an additional or different library.